# Are the products of different independent random variables independent?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

I'm confused about the independence of the product of independent random variables.

Let `A` and `B` be independent of each other and `C` and `D` also be independent of each other, then I understand that `AC` and `CB` are not necessarily independent each other.

However, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are mutually independent of each other.

In that case, are `AC` and `BD` independent of each other?

Comment: I think you mean AC and BD in the first case ? (not CB)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: yes. If $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are mutually independent, that means that:

- $A$ si independent of $(B,C,D)$
- $B$ is independent of $(A,C,D)$
- ....
- $(A,B)$ is independent of $(C,D)$
- $(A,C)$ is independent of $(B,D)$
- ...

Moreover, saying that $(A,C)$ is independent of $(B,D)$ means that for all (Borelian) real-valued functions $f$ and $g$, the two random variables $f(A,C)$ and $g(B,D)$ are independent, thereby implying the answer to your question.